# Keep ssh connection active

Tags: python

I have made a library who looks like this :

```
class AXISSetGet(object):

    def SSH_Start(self):
        cfg = yaml.load(open(config_file_path))
        HOST =  cfg['afo_axis_host']
        PORT = cfg['afo_axis_port']
        USERNAME = cfg['afo_axis_username']
        PASSWORD = cfg['afo_axis_password']

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname=HOST, port=PORT, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)

    def Get_File (self,filename):
    # rest of the function
```

SSH_Start() function is needed in every others functions of the class.
I tried to write the SSH_Start() before declaring the class but it doesn't work..

Can anyone help me on this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use self to access functions of the same class like this, I guess this is what you want?

```
class AXISSetGet(object):

    def SSH_Start(self):
        cfg = yaml.load(open(config_file_path))
        HOST =  cfg['afo_axis_host']
        PORT = cfg['afo_axis_port']
        USERNAME = cfg['afo_axis_username']
        PASSWORD = cfg['afo_axis_password']

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname=HOST, port=PORT, username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD)

    def Get_File (self,filename):
        self.SSH_Start()
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of calling the function every time needed.. As I know I need it everywhere. I'll look for Holloway's answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Add the SSH client as an instance attribute that can then be used from any method. From your existing code, I don't think you want to call the SSH_Start method more than once, you just need the SSH connection to be open. Try something like:

```
class AXISSetGet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.SSH_Start() # Call it here to ensure the connection has been made before it's needed.

    def SSH_Start(self):
        # config stuff

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        # ...
        self.ssh = ssh

    def Get_File (self,filename):
        self.ssh.use_client_here(...)
```

I would be tempted to look at [properties](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) here. That way, the first time you try and use the client, it will create one and connect, then it will use the existing one for subsequent calls. Something like:

```
class AXISSetGet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._ssh = None

    @property
    def ssh(self):
        # if this is the first time the connection has been needed, create it
        if not self._ssh:
            # config stuff
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            # ...
            self._ssh = ssh
        # and then just return the existing one
        return self._ssh

    def Get_File (self,filename):
        self.ssh.use_client_here(...)
```

Just as a side note, have a read through of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for guidelines about naming conventions and formatting. It doesn't change how the code behaves but make it easier for others to read and understand.

Comment: I'll try this, and tell you. But I like the idea of calling the function just one time.